# HoloLens 2 doesnt connection problem to unreal 4.27

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality, openxr

I am having a connection problem with hololens 2 and unreal 4.27.

I am trying to deploy my project to hololens 2 and it is not happening.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV5Qa.png)

I am using openxr and mrtk plugins.

I also tried uxttools and windows mixed reality plugin in 4.25, use holographic remoting to connect.
here is the tutorial i watched > https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=u_qR-1DrvMg&t=80s

still not happening. I know for sure it is not like a firewall or a network problem because I can connect via Unity.

Comment: Is there any error message in the Holographic Remoting Player on HoloLens? What is the version of your Holographic Remoting Player? Have you restarted Unreal after checking Enable Remoting? Please check the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch6#device-only-streaming. Also, make sure you are not using any network management software, such as a VPN.

Comment: well i actually didnt use holographic player on hololens because none of the videos talked about them. i downloaded it and it works now, thank you so much !